# Can I deploy FIWARE IDAS communicating with an Orion Context Broker instance running on a different virtual machine from IDAS?

Tags: fiware-orion

I want to deploy an IDAS (FIWARE Backend Device Manager) i.e. IOTA instance that will communicate and send data to an already existing Orion Context Broker instance running in a different virtual machine from the one hosting IDAS. Is that possible? Or is it necessary for the two services to be in the same virtual machine?

I am using an IoTAgent-JSON (I think it's 1.6.2 version) for MQTT transport.

This is the config.js file (I have already replaced the contextBroker host with the host of my Orion Context Broker, as you can see, it was "localhost" before):

```
var config = {};
config.mqtt = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 1883,
    thinkingThingsPlugin: true
};
config.iota = {
    logLevel: 'DEBUG',
    timestamp: true,
    contextBroker: {
        host: '147.27.60.182',
        port: '1026'
    },
    server: {
        port: 4041
    },
    deviceRegistry: {
        type: 'mongodb'
    },
    mongodb: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: '27017',
        db: 'iotagentjson'
    },
    types: {},
    service: 'howtoService',
    subservice: '/howto',
```

**IoTA endpoints:** 
http://147.27.60.202:5351/iot/services
(Fiware-Service: openiot, Fiware-ServicePath: /, X-Auth-Token: [TOKEN])

http://147.27.60.202:4041/iot/devices/
(Fiware-Service: tourguide, Fiware-ServicePath: /)

**My Orion Context Broker (where I want to send data) endpoint:** 
http://147.27.60.182:1026/v2

*P.S.: I have tried to change the mongodb host, too.*

[Image: how the service runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFzA0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have Orion and one or more IOTAs running in different virtual machine. The only requirement is mutual interconnection, I mean IOTA needs access to the Orion endpoint and Orion needs access to IOTA endpoint.

Check `contextBroker.url` (alternatively `contextBroker.host` and `contextBroker.port`) and `providerUrl` IOTA configuration parameters in [IOTA documentation](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/blob/master/doc/installationguide.md).

Comment: Note that IDAS is an old name no longer used to describe the component that connects devices to Orion. Now the name we use the connect of IOTA (IoT Agent), each one specialized in a given device protocol and transport type (i.e. IOTA-UL, IOTA-JSON, IOTA-Sigfox, etc.) but all them sharing a library of common functionality.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support! I have already changed these parameters but nothing changed, data is sent to an existing Orion instance in the same virtual machine with IOTA (but I need to send data in another Orion instance). I am making POST HTTP requests in <IOTA_host>:4041/iot/devices/ and data is always sent to the Orion Broken hosted in the same VM. To be more exact, I am entering the iotagent-json folder in the VM and in the file config.js I am changing the contextBroker parameters as you said. Do I have I change something else, too?

Comment: What's more, a POST request has already been sent to <IOTA_host>:5351/iot/services (by the guy who developed the IOTA I am using) and the "cbroker" parameter in this request contains the ContextBroker host and port hosted in the same VM with the IOTA. How can I change that now?

Comment: Could you edit your question post to specify which particular IOTA are you using, please? In addition, please include the config.js file you are using and the command you are using for starting it, please. Thanks!

Comment: I've just done the edit. I'm not sure about the command you asked for, though. I just edit the config.js file, I save it and then restart the IOTA service in the VM (every time I make a change). Which command do you mean?

Comment: In this case, it would be the command you use to restart the IOTA service. In addition, it would be great to know how the service management system actually runs the IOTA (`ps ax | grep node` should provide the answer).

Comment: Oh, great! I didn't know that. The command I use to restart the IOTA service is: 
sudo service idas restart.

Comment: To have the full picture, I'd also need to know how the process runs in the OS. `ps ax | grep node` or `ps ax | grep iota-json`) should provide that information. Please, edit your question post to include that information.

Comment: First thing to check is connectivity from the machine where the IOTA-JSON process runs to CB. I mean, for instance, to execute `curl http://147.27.60.182:1026/version` from the machine where IOTA-JSON process runs. Which result do you get?

Comment: I get that result: 
{
"orion" : {
  "version" : "2.2.0",
  "uptime" : "91 d, 1 h, 25 m, 5 s",
  "git_hash" : "5a46a70de9e0b809cce1a1b7295027eea0aa757f",
  "compile_time" : "Wed Mar 27 15:08:03 UTC 2019",
  "compiled_by" : "root",
  "compiled_in" : "c5848811fd25",
  "release_date" : "Wed Mar 27 15:08:03 UTC 2019",
  "doc" : "https://fiware-orion.rtfd.io/en/2.2.0/"
}
}

Comment: I'd suggest to check IOTA logs. Maybe they show some relevant information about why CB is not reachable. I understand you have the setup working when IOTA and CB are located in the same virtual machine, so you can try to reproduce the same case in the faulty case and compare IOTA logs with the working case.